# Laravel - how to load Session Class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am quite new to Laravel, I have create a custom class of Session, for example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class SessionProgress {

    public function storePersonalDetails($store)
    {
        Session::put('company.personal_details', $store);
    }

    public function getPersonalDetails()
    {
        return Session::get('company.personal_details', []);
    }
}
```

Where could I save `SessionProgress` class file in a Laravel \app folder and how to allow class controller files be able to access to `SessionProgress`class (or how it should be done)?

Comment: To be able to use it like `Session` (`SessionProgress::store...`) you need to [create a facade](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#creating-facades)

Comment: @lukasgeiter please post answer with example of `SessionProgress`

Comment: Actually I read the question a bit wrong. A facade doesn't help with loading the class it only provides a convenient way to use it. So an answer regarding facades would be pretty off-topic.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Ah ok, what is other solution apart from facade

Comment: Jerodev's answer is what you need ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/app/start/global.php` you should add the folder where this class is located to the ClassLoader:

For example:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/my_session_classes' // <--- Add this

));
```

This will load all classes in that folder.

Comment: After that, what I need to do for a controller class to load a session class file in `my_session_classes` for example? you could expand your answer a bit more.

Comment: Then you can create objects of the type `SessionProgress` anywhere in your project. I would recommend using static functions though.

Comment: What about Composer.json file?

Comment: You could also add the class path there. Don't forget to use `php artisan optimize` after that.